Why when differentiating $y=e^x v(x)$ an additional chain rule is not needed?
The correct answer is to do product rule and get $y' = v'e^x + ve^x$
But when differentiating v, don't we have to do some kind of chain rule? Is it because v is a function of x, just like y?

I think you meant $y(x) = e^{x}v(x)$

@ÁtilaCorreia Yeah. Its just common for my professors in Singapore to drop the (x) part when writing functions out.

The function in the title does not match the function in the body of the question.

Do you mean $y=e^xv(x)$ in the title?

Ah thanks for that, I have changed the title

Your first line is mis-stated. It should say: "The correct answer is to do the product rule and get ..."

There is no rule that tells you what $v'$ is unless you tell us  what $v$ is.

You are right. If v was a function of z and z was a function of x(say), then Differentiating v wrt x would mean that Differentiating v wrt z times Differentiating z wrt x. But here since v is a function of x directly and there is no intermediary variable so no chain rule applies here.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
